# Urwids Edit Widget not updating when using custom List Walker

Tags: python-3.6, urwid

I'm trying to use a custom List Walker which manages an infinite number of Edit widgets. Key presses seem to reach Edit widgets successfully, however they don't seem to update in any way. How could I go about solving this?

My List Walker looks like this:

```py
class MyWalker(urwid.ListWalker):
    def __init__(self):
        self.focus = 0

    def get_focus(self):
        return urwid.Edit('Selected : %s' % self.focus), self.focus

    def set_focus(self, pos):
        self.focus = pos
        self._modified()

    def get_next(self, pos):
        return urwid.Edit(edit_text='This is: %d' % (pos+1)), pos+1

    def get_prev(self, pos):
        return urwid.Edit(edit_text='This is: %d' % (pos-1)), pos-1
```

I start the MainLoop as follows:

```py
walker = MyWalker()
listbox = urwid.ListBox(walker)
urwid.MainLoop(listbox).run()
```